# show the values of string variables in a string array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

I created an array of strings and I want to get the value of a given string at a given position, but the returned value is the character and not the string, eg:

```
myArray = ['string1' 'string2' 'string3'];
s = myArray(1); //returns the character at the position 1, instead of the string
```

How can I get the value of these strings based on a given position i ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a cell array:

```
myArray = {'string1' 'string2' 'string3'};
s = myArray{1};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a for loop if this is what you are asking for.

```
myArray=['b' 'c' 'd']
for i =1:lenght(myArray)
s(i)=myArray(i);

end
```

Not sure what you are asking for exactly.

Comment: Thanks, the correct answer to my question is above :) s=myarray{1}='string1' and not 's' which is the first character.  I wanted to get the first string.